# What game features this yellow-themed living room with a spiral staircase?

Tags: game-identification

I see this game everywhere, but I'm not sure of the name:

[image: cartoony living room with yellow furnishings]

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the yellow themed design lounge from the game Adorable Home.

Comment: I first thought it was Neko Atsume! It's actually the same people who made both games